# System directory files (to access PWM pins) are missing from by Beaglebone Black rev C

Tags: linux, debian, beaglebone

So I'm trying to set up my beaglebone black so that I can access the PWM pins. Initially I was following [this](https://briancode.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/working-with-pwm-on-a-beaglebone-black/) tutorial but it's telling me to access an ocp file, which my beaglebone doesn't have.

```
debian@beaglebone:/sys/devices$ ls
armv7_cortex_a8  breakpoint  platform  soc0  software  system  tracepoint  virtual
```

I've looked up a number of other guides and they all say the same thing. I should eventually be able to go into my pwm folder and export the pin (using the export/unexport files) but that's also missing.

```
debian@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm$ ls
pwm-0:0  pwm-0:1  pwm-2:0  pwm-2:1  pwm-4:0  pwm-4:1  pwmchip0  pwmchip2  pwmchip4
```

I'm able to use the GPIO pins just fine, and I'm running the default image, found [here](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images). It's made without a GUI and is based on debian 9.5 kernel version `4.14.71-ti-r80`

Any insight into this would be helpful, including general troubleshooting, packages I might need to install, or things I can do to get my image working again. I don't want to flash a new debian version onto my beaglebone since I've compiled a number of binaries onto it, and it takes tens of hours to compile and install some of the libraries I'm using (specifically opencv).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've been able to figure this out.

Effectively around version 4.14 of the linux kernel, the started changing the hardware overlays for the pwm pin; since then it's gone through minor revisions but has largely stayed the same. What I was using was I was looking at the pre-4.14 version.

I've found [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203064/pwm-on-beaglebone-black-v4-14) which is similar to mine, and explains how the new system works. It's accurate for the most part, however I'm using v4.19 and the file names are no longer pwm0 or pwm1 but are pwm0:0 or pwm0:1.

Essentially this question links to [this github example by beaglebone](https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/examples/cape-unversal-pwm.txt), which lays out how they want you to use it and is worth looking at. But to summarize you can run

```
debian@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm$ ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3  2016 pwm-0:0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm-0:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3  2016 pwm-0:1 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm-0:1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3  2016 pwm-2:0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48302000.epwmss/48302200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm-2:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3  2016 pwm-2:1 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48302000.epwmss/48302200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip2/pwm-2:1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3  2016 pwm-4:0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48304000.epwmss/48304200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip4/pwm-4:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3  2016 pwm-4:1 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48304000.epwmss/48304200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip4/pwm-4:1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  2000 pwmchip0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  2000 pwmchip2 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48302000.epwmss/48302200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  2000 pwmchip4 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48304000.epwmss/48304200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip4
```

Which gives you the location of all the pwm pins (with the exception of pin 42; I don't know how to get to that one). To turn on pin 14 for example, you could then run

```
export ehrpwm1=/sys/devices/platform/ocp/48302000.epwmss/48302200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip2
echo 0 > ${ehrpwm1}/export || true
echo 20000 > ${ehrpwm1}/pwm2:0/period
echo 10000 > ${ehrpwm1}/pwm2:0/duty_cycle
echo 1 > ${ehrpwm1}/pwm2:0/enable
```

I've heard this changes from board to board though so I'd follow the example and make sure your folder structures line up.

I've also written a library to use the pwm pins if you're interested, it's what I'm using and it's worked well. I will note though that I haven't tried it on other versions of beaglebone but it works well for linux kernel version 4.19 https://github.com/Haxonek/wiringbeaglelite